# How to get Wifi-Pumpkin to work?

Tags: kali-linux

I have searched a lot of places and posted the question to other places too. I open Wifi-Pumpkin, select the adaptor, and name the network; everything says it's ok. I press start at the bottom of the gui it says its connected to the internet and turns green, when I connect to the ap there is no internet. It is also changing my `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` configuration file for my USB wifi adapter to `device=unmanaged` and I have to go to the file and delete the un from unmanaged then the wifi adapter works again. I didn't include a log because it doesn't show any errors, if you want one I can post it. I'm using Kali 2019.3 rolling from a USB. Every tool works except The Pumpkin and evil access. Monitor works and injection. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry /root/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: I'd expect NetworkManager to set the adaptor to `unmanaged` while you're running Pumpkin, so that NetworkManager doesn't try to grab it back again. Given that, what's the problem?

Comment: It was leaving it that way, and is killing all wifi. I have no connection even though it says it's working. Thank you for your help.